# Using rails as the omniauth provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth

I'm not entirely sure what to google. It seems everything I have googled just show me links to how to leverage omniauth to authenticate with other sites(facebook, twitter, github etc etc). That's simple and easy. What I want is the how to build that feature in a rails app, the functionalities that those sites (facebook, twitter, github) have that allow third party auth.

Here's the feature I'd like to build:

I have two separate applications, applications A and B. Let's say application A is the rails app that I want providing the authentication. And application B is using omniauth to login through application A.

How do I get started building that feature for application A?

Now, that's a loaded question, but if anyone could point to a resource I could start with that would be amazing! Thanks.